# Android recycle view with swipe effect on click listener not working

Tags: android

I am implementing an app that display list of data on a RecycleView. After swipe a recycleview item it display a specific LinearLayout view. In that view I have implemented an onClickListner. But it's not calling on click.

Comment: add some code and logcat if you are getting some error or exception

Comment: I am not getting any error, I have used ItemTouchHelper class to implement swipe effect.

Comment: u want to swipe delete or what ?@Darshana

Comment: I am displaying a specific view for recycleview item after swiped. In that view I want to implement an onClickListner

Comment: can you tired for this kind of output if ***YES*** then paste your code hear

Answer (score 0):

You must create an `OnItemClickListener()` interface.
Then, put this in your `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
```

Next time, put the bind method inside of your Adapter:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(item);
        }
    });
```

And finally, in your MainActivity inside of your adapter declaration open the listener like this:

```
recycler.setAdapter(new ContentAdapter(items, new ContentAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(ContentItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}));
```

If you want to read more check out [this documentation](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

Comment: Thank you very much tung, how can you verify I have knowledge about programming languages ​​but the english language I am still learning ...